# Is woodworking history an acceptable topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggested a new tag called [woodworking-history](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woodworking-history). Is this an appropriate topic for this site?

This would not cover any questions related to the "act" of woodworking (such as the typical "How can I..." questions) for people who are seeking advice on what they should do. This would be more of an educational topic that could be used to help someone better understand a technique or tool for their benefit (in my opinion). I could also see this being used as a purely informative topic for the sake of curiosity.

My question as a reference for this Meta... [When did people start using plywood rather than real hardwood?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/when-did-people-start-using-plywood-rather-than-real-hardwood)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no reason not to at this point. As long as the question can stand by the sites basic standards then it should be fine.

Even if there is not an answer, due to lack of known citable sources, it can still be a good question and sit there until we get an answer.

History is fun and we already have at least one question that in that same vien:

[What is the difference between a sabre saw and a jig saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sabre-saw-and-a-jig-saw)

My answer for that delved into history as many other answers have. While I don't think the question I linked to deserves the tag it does show that history has its merits here at WW.

Bring on the questions I say.

---

**Tag Suggestion**

As for the tag though [woodworking-history](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woodworking-history) might be redundant since it is a woodworking site *I* would expect that part of the tag to be implied. I think [history](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is fine on its own. The tag name might be its own question.

Comment: That's a great point. "History" might be a better choice. Any idea how I can change it?

Comment: I agree on both accounts!  @Hooplehead24, I've updated the tag.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks